# crosswalk-lite in ionic cli v1.4.4 does not reduce apk size

Tags: ionic-framework, crosswalk-runtime

Tried many times, the apk file size does not change.

```
ionic revert android;
ionic browser add crosswalk-lite
ionic build android
```

I also tried remove android platform and do from scratch, but never suceeded.

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.0.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.8.11
Gulp local:   Local version 3.8.11
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.20
OS: Distributor ID:     Ubuntu Description:     Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS 
Node Version: v0.12.3
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29573069/how-to-build-android-with-crosswalk-lite-using-ionic-cli

Comment: You should post your `ionic info`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same here.
I guess crosswalk-lite is so new that ionic still doesn't quite cope with it. Or it did, but things have changed now.

When I run:

```
ionic browser remove crosswalk
ionic browser remove crosswalk-lite
ionic browser add crosswalk-lite
```

I get this `ionic.project`file:

```
{                                  
  "name": "chapter5",              
  "app_id": "27fa0870",            
  "browsers": [                    
    {                              
      "platform": "android",       
      "browser": "crosswalk-lite", 
      "version": "12.41.296.5"     
    }                              
  ]                                
}
```

`ionic info` output:

```
Cordova CLI: 4.2.0                                               
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.8.11                                
Gulp local:                                                      
Ionic Version: 1.0.0-rc.0                                        
Ionic CLI Version: 1.4.5                                         
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.0.22                                    
OS: Distributor ID:     Fedora Description:     Fedora release 21
 (Twenty One)                                                    
Node Version: v0.10.36
```

Also, take notice of your cordova-android version, when you run `browser add`:

```
Android project created with cordova-android@4.0.0-dev
```

And your cordova-crosswalk-engine. Mine says: `c0.7.1`

Those are all inter-related and may lead to weird errors.

Comment: Does crosswalk-lite support iOS?

Comment: I don't think IOS need crosswalk at all. I do not build for IOS, but I guess crosswalk is only added to the android platform.

Comment: Crosswalk does support iOS but I'm asking about the lite version