# How to integrate with crosswalk lite with ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, crosswalk

I am searching for crosswalk and it;s still making the apk above 20 mb...

Is there any workout to make it smaller ?

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/42314666/3966458

Answer (score 5):

If you already have Crosswalk plugin uninstall it with Cordova CLI :
`cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview`

And then install Crosswalk in Lite mode : `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview  --variable XWALK_MODE="lite"`

APK size before : 27.9 MB, after: 15.5 MB

cf. https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-5189

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the problem is with Chromium. The code is not modular, so the Crosswalk team can't separate specyfic features.

So the answer is NO. At this moment you can't minimalize app size :(