# crosswalk in Ionic2 increases app size by 25 MB

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm using `Ionic2`,my app size is 9.9MBm, then I installed `crosswalk` to improve the app performance but the app size became 31.5 MB, Are there any alternative solutions for that ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30391023/71mb-added-to-app-size-for-crosswalk this link will help you to reduce the size

Comment: @rJ7 don't understand how to use crosswalk light instead of cross walk ?

Comment: https://crosswalk-project.org/jira/browse/XWALK-5189 refer this link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37992904/how-to-integrate-with-crosswalk-lite-with-ionic this answer will be useful for you